# image-shadow behind the main div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, shadow

I have the following HTML source:

```
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <!-- end header div -->
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown">
       <!--navigator menu is here!-->
        </div>

    <div id="main">
 <!--main is here!-->
     </div>
       <div id="sidebar">
           <!--sidebar menu is here!--></div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
        <!-- end page div -->
    </div>
    <div id="leftshadow"></div>
    <div id="rightshadow"></div>
</body>
```

And this is the CSS source

```
/* html selectors ---- */

html, body {
    font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: white;
    direction: rtl;
    font-size: 10.3pt;
}



/*page -----------*/
#page {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction: rtl;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: url("images/bgimage.png");
}

#leftshadow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 900px;
    background-image: url("images/leftshadow.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: 1220px;
    z-index: none;
    top: -50px;
}

#rightshadow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 900px;
    background-image: url("images/rightshadow.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: 345px;
    z-index: none;
    top: -25px;
}


/* header ---------- */

#header {
    height: 110px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-image: url("images/header.png");
    background-position-x: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


/* main -------------- */



#main {
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: arial;
    width: 625px;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: 205px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    direction: rtl;
    top: 42px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    min-height: 750px;

      text-align: justify;

}
```

Normally I got this result [image: what I want]

But in Internet-Explorer I got this result [image: What I get]

I know that if I will insert the

```
   <div id="leftshadow"></div>
         <div id="rightshadow"></div>
```

******Live example here! http://lawb.co.il/******

Into the #page Div the problem could be solved, but the only problem is that the shadow than is complatly on the content, und not behund him

Can you pleas help me with this?

wish for help, thanks!

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck What is CSS reset?

Comment: It resets all of your browsers CSS back to zero so they are all the same. By default all browsers will set different type of padding and margin on HTML elements. It is highly recommended to use one every time you create a new web project. It prevents a lot of layout inconsistencies between browsers. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Hi, Thanks for your anser, I tried but it still didn't work, why?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason as to why you are using images to create shadows when you could use CSS3 [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)?

If you are going to use this approach I would change your HTML structure like so:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="leftshadow"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <!-- end header div -->
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <!--navigator menu is here!-->
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <!--main is here!-->
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!--sidebar menu is here!-->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- end page div -->
    <div id="rightshadow"></div>
</div>
```

And then float the right shadow div to the right and the left shadow div to the left. Most likely you are seeing inconsistencies because 
you are not using a reset, and stuff is relatively positioned. You really don't need to position everything relative and the shadows if inside the `#page` container won't need to be positioned absolute.

Comment: I use image becouse it is not regular shadow, it is ver very complicated to create it in css shadow (this is the image: http://lawb.co.il/images/leftshadow.png)
I tried to use CSS reset  - and insert the shaows divs into the page div, but still, the page Div is above them...